# Check if PHP variable is contained in SQL field

Tags: php, sql

Is the following possible?

field in DB contains: 1,2,3,4

```
$a=1;

$selqry="select * from table where field={contains $a}";
```

Thanks,
B.

Comment: The question is "only" marked as [sql]. Do you really want to keep it database-system-agnostic?

Answer (score 1):

MySQL's [FIND_IN_SET(str,strlist) function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) can help you there (edit: oops.... in case you're using MySQL)

> Returns a value in the range of 1 to N if the string str is in the string list strlist consisting of N substrings. A string list is a string composed of substrings separated by “,” characters.

```
SELECT
  x,y,z
FROM
  tablename
WHERE
  FIND_IN_SET(':id', field)
```

(If you're not using [pdo/prepared statements](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements), replace :id by the value of $a but make sure it encoded/escaped properly)

It's not perfectly index-friendly though... you'll end up with a full-table scan having this function in your WHERE-clause.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, it's possible.

1. If you don't mind `"1"` matching `"2,3,11,4"`. You can do it using `INSTR` or `LIKE`. Example:

   ```
   SELECT *
   FROM tbl
   WHERE INSTR(field, '1') != 0
   ```
2. If you don't want `"1"` to match `"2,3,11,4"`, you'll have to use a (slow) regex if your DBMS supports it (MySQL, for example, does):

   ```
   SELECT *
   FROM tbl
   WHERE field REGEXP '[[:<:]]1[[:>:]]'
   ```

However, a better question is whether this is a good idea. And the answer to that is a resounding **no**. You should not store multiple values in a single field. A case like this would really benefit from [normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).

Comment: The not equal to 0 (!= 0
) - why is that needed?

The field will only contain numbers from 1 to 8

Thanks.

Comment: It's not really needed since 0 is synonymous with "false" in SQL. It just underlines the fact that `INSTR()` returns a string position rather than a contains/does not contain boolean.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what you're asking but why not just do a `LIKE`, it should work on numeric fields too:

```
SELECT * FROM foo WHERE id like '%1%';
```

This will match `001`, `100`, and `101`, `010`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If field only contain numbers from 1-8 you can do it simple

```
$selqry="select * from table where field like '%" . intval($a) . "%'";
```

You "should" probably move field to another table and use a query joining the tables based on id.